# Care vs Maintenance

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Currently we have some tags such as [brush-maintenance](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brush-maintenance)  and [pencil-maintenance](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil-maintenance), which I believe are my doing.

But that seems overly formal and wordy, and [tool-care](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-care) where you replace `tool` with the actual tool, media or implement, such as `pencil` or `brush`, seems like a better fit, to me.

Should we use `care` or `maintenance`? Something else?

Should we synonymize them? If yes, which should be the primary?

This should be for general naming policy, not just the listed tags.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is going to be a great distinction between them. In each case, there is a broad definition of *keeping my tool or material in good working order*. But when you get into more detail, it gets tricky.

To my mind:

- *Care* implies regular actions that you'd do to preserve the quality of an item, such as washing a paintbrush right after use or keeping a cap on sharpened pencils so they don't break in your backpack. I might also *take care* of art/craft supplies -- keeping a lid on paints so they don't dry up, or pre-balling yarn so it doesn't tangle into an unusable mess.
- *Maintenance* implies an intermittent activity. I might not sharpen a craft knife each time I work on a papercutting project, but instead do so every twenty projects.

In either case, standardizing language is going to end up with some odd-sounding options. "Knife Care" could easily [sound like being careful around knives](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185/care-vs-maintenance/186#comment418_186). "Pencil Maintenance" isn't as natural a phrase to me as "Pencil Care", since I sharpen and store colored pencils constantly. "Yarn Maintenance" sounds funny.

Tags not only need to be descriptive, but also easily findable -- if users won't naturally think about "maintenance" when asking about caring for a paintbrush, it isn't as good a tag as brush-care.

Comment: So take a case by case look at the choice and use what is natural.

Comment: If we're going to have thing-maintenance tags for many things, i think it's worth looking at each on its own to see how that field's experts talk about it -- yes.

Comment: -1 for inconsistency, +2 for common sense :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `-care` suffix looks nicer, is less formal, and includes situations where you're not necessarily maintaining the tool, such as this question:

[What is the proper way to sharpen a pencil?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/457/what-is-the-proper-way-to-sharpen-a-pencil)

As the perpetrator of the '-maintenance' suffix, as a result of [this meta discussion](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111/24), I would undo the action. At the time, we didn't discuss alternative naming conventions, so I went with the decision at hand.

I don't think synonyms are necessary, as "maintenance" can be included in the wiki excerpt, making it easy to find if typing in the tool, such as "brush" doesn't bring it up immediately, anyway.

In general, I would avoid having overly-wordy or "stiff" tag and opt for a more informal naming convention when not using specific technical terms.

Answer (score 1):

I am particular to the "tool"-maintenance naming convention and I think we should stick with it for now.

I also think there is no need to create the synonyms at this time. When someone types in `pencil` for the start of the tag the limited / suggested options will be narrowed down and I would expect `-maintenance` to be one of the ones presented.

Tag experts will help but I think the name is clear as to what it is intended for.

The way this could change is if there is a maintenance that does not already exist and someone creates that tag and uses `-care`. If that indeed happens we could reconsider but I don't see it so the work involved would outweigh the gain I think.

Comment: I was contemplating retagging them all -care, myself, but figured I'd ask the community first. There's only a few questions tagged as such, and I'm pretty sure I was the one to do that after our other maintenance meta decision.

Comment: @CreationEdge You might as well answer from that point of view. Give it a few days and hopefully we could get a good idea of what to do. Either way I don't think the synonyms are necessary and we should get a consensus before there are too many of these.

Comment: Care doesn't seem clear to me the way maintenance does. Knife care could be "being careful around knives", for example. Knife maintenance doesn't have that ambiguity.